# Сдвиг на мобильном виде

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вот сайт: [u-cpa.ru/p/](http://u-cpa.ru/p/)

Если перейти в режим мобильного просмотра, то на всех вариантах мобильных устройств в вертикальном положении есть небольшой скролл справа:

[image: c77f13439eed4a46b8fcf99308c03881.png]

Bootstrap чистый. Догадываюсь, что где-то что-то намудрил по незнанию, но уже сломал голову второй день себе.

Еще стоит отметить, сайт ориентирован на 99% трафика с xs-устройств

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В подобных ситуациях, чтобы выявить проблемный блок - действуйте так:

1. Открывайте веб-инспектор, переходите на вкладку `Elements` (там, где html-элементы) и поочередно удаляйте крупные блоки, наблюдая за скроллом;
2. Если скролл исчез - значит только что вы удалили проблемный блок;
3. Перезагружайте страницу, в веб-инспекторе переходите внутрь этого блока и изучайте его элементы, можно так же удалением и наблюдением за скроллом.

Конкретно в вашем случае - проблема была вот в этом блоке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А точнее - в свойстве `padding: 5px;`. В бутстрапе, **не задавайте padding и margin для блоков col-xx и row** - рискуете получить поехавшую верстку.

Уберете свойство padding у этого блока - скролл исчезнет. Рекомендую пройтись и по другим блокам - как минимум вот здесь тоже установлены лишние padding'и:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]